# Динамический вывод информации в сообщение для Телеграм бота на Pyhon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Делаю бота для Телеграма и столкнулся с необходимостью динамически дополнять сообщение, которое постит бот. Сейчас постараюсь нагляднее объяснить. Имеется такой код:

```
@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
@auth
async def welcome(message: Message):
    parse()
    for full_item_name, paintseed, floatvalue, price, item_url, stickers_dict in itertools.zip_longest(items['full_item_name'], items['paintseed'], items['floatvalue'], items['price'], items['item_url'], items['stickers_dict']):
        open_tp = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn_to_tp = InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Открыть ТП', url = item_url)
        open_tp.add(btn_to_tp)
        time.sleep(1)
        await bot.send_message(channel_id, f"""
{full_item_name}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Наклейки:
▫️ 1: {stickers_dict[0]['name']}
▫️ 2: {stickers_dict[1]['name']}
▫️ 3: {stickers_dict[2]['name']}
▫️ 4: {stickers_dict[3]['name']}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
▫️ Pattern: {paintseed}
▫️ Float: {floatvalue}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
▫️ Стоимость на ТП: {price}₴
--------------------------------------------------------------------
""", reply_markup = open_tp)
```

Одна из переменных, которая передаётся в цикл for это **stickers_dict**, которая является словарём со следующей структурой:

```
{
0:
    {
    'stickerId': 4144,
    'slot': 0,
    'codename': 'berlin2019_signature_magisk',
    'name': 'Magisk | Berlin 2019'
    },
1:
    {
    'stickerId': 4195,
    'slot': 1,
    'codename': 'berlin2019_signature_electronic',
    'name': 'electronic | Berlin 2019'},
2:
    {
    'stickerId': 4306,
    'slot': 2,
    'codename': 'berlin2019_signature_sanji',
    'name': 'SANJI | Berlin 2019',
    'wear': 0.1415986716747284
    },
3:
    {
    'stickerId': 4189,
    'slot': 3,
    'codename': 'berlin2019_signature_zeus',
    'name': 'Zeus | Berlin 2019'
}
}
```

При чём словарь динамический, в нём может содержатся разное количество значений по типу 0, 1, 2..., а также поле **wear** присутствует не везде.
Вопрос в следующем: как мне выводить информацию, которая содержится в этом словаре. На данный момент делал это так:

```
Наклейки:
▫️ 1: {stickers_dict[0]['name']}
▫️ 2: {stickers_dict[1]['name']}
▫️ 3: {stickers_dict[2]['name']}
▫️ 4: {stickers_dict[3]['name']}
```

но проблема в том, что элементов может быть больше или меньше, поле wear, которое я тоже буду выводить, присутствует не везде. Можно ли как-то запустить цикл внутри структуры по типу такого:

```
await bot.send_message(channel_id, f"""
*тут цикл по типу for number in stickers_dict*
""", reply_markup = open_tp)
```

Тонкости самого цикла я продумаю сам, нужна помощь конкретно с тем, как вообще это сделать. Буду благодарен всем, кто поможет. Спасибо

Comment: разделите ваше одно большое сообщение на несколько маленьких, а ту часть которая будет отвечать за `Наклейки` формируйте в цикле по типу `строка += данные с итерации` и в конце склейте всё в одно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как подсказал человек выше, разделил сообщение на блоки а потом соединил и вывел